# Swift String: How do you replace two-character ( \" ) with the single character quote ( " )?

Tags: swift, string

I'm trying to replace all incidences of ( \" ) with only the quote mark: ( " ).
I tried:

```
let pattern = "\\""; let replacePattern = ""\"""
let result = scrubbedJsonString?.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: replacePattern)
```

Trying to de-nuke the special character '\' with a double '\ \'. 
Ditto with the double-quote: ' " '

[image]
It's not working.

Remedy?

Comment: I think you can use raw strings for this.

Comment: There is no backslash in your string. Just print it to see that they are not there

Answer (score 3):

First of all consider that the backslashes might be *virtual*...

You have to escape the backslash, too.

```
let pattern = "\\\""
```

Or use the modern syntax (Swift 5+)

```
let pattern = #"\""#
```

Answer (score 0):

`\\` is a backslash and `\"` is a single quote.

```swift
let pattern = "\\\""; let replacePattern = "\""
let result = scrubbedJsonString?.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: replacePattern)
```

or better yet, use extended delimiters to remove all the backslashiness.

```swift
let pattern = #"\""#; let replacePattern = #"""#
let result = scrubbedJsonString?.replacingOccurrences(of: pattern, with: replacePattern)
```